# How does `fit` function in scikit-learn make validation?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

I am having trouble with `fit` function when applied to `MLPClassifier`. I carefully read [Scikit-Learn's documentation about that](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier) but was not able to determine how validation works.

Is it cross-validation or is there a split between training and validation data ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fit` function per se does not include cross-validation and also does not apply a train test split. 
Fortunately you can do this by your own.

**Train Test split:**

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33) // test set size is 0.33 
clf = MLPClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train) 
clf.predict(X_test, y_test) // predict on test set
```

**K-Fold cross validation**

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
kf = KFold(n_splits=2)
kf.get_n_splits(X)
clf = MLPClassifier()
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
   X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
   y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

   clf.fit(X_train, y_train) 
   clf.predict(X_test, y_test) // predict on test set
```

For cross validation multiple functions are available, you can read more about it [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.model_selection). The here stated k-fold is just an example.

**EDIT:**

> Thanks for this answer, but basically how does fit function works
>   concretely ? It just trains the network on the given data (i.e.
>   training set) until max_iter is reached and that's it ?

I am assuming your are using the default config of `MLPClassifier`. In this case the fit function tries to do an optimization on basis of adam optimizer. In this case, indeed, the network trains until max_iter is reached.

> Moreover, in the K-Fold cross validation, is the model improving as
>   long as the loop goes through or just restarts from scratch ?

Actually cross-validation is not used to improve the performance of your network, it's actually a methodology to test how well your algrotihm generalizes on different data. For k-fold, k independent classifiers are trained and tested.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but basically how does `fit`function works concretely ? It just trains the network on the given data (i.e. training set) until `max_iter` is reached and that's it ? Moreover, in the K-Fold cross validation, is the model improving as long as the loop goes through or just restarts from scratch ? I'll be glad if you could update your answer taking it into account !

Comment: When I make the `fit` function (default parameters), I get a couple of `Iterations` before displaying "Training loss did not improve more than..." What does that iterations mean ?